# python selenium 403 Error Forbidden

Tags: python, selenium, http-status-code-403

При попытки зайти на сайт ашана, получаю ошибку 403. Из-за чего такое происходит? Как решить проблему?
ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.auchan.ru')

sleep(10)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить вопрос? Та же проблема с Edge/Selenium. Решается странным способом - если зайти на https://www.auchan.ru вручную браузером с тем же профилем и затем выйти, Selenium начинает работать до завершения текущей сессии. Затем снова та же ошибка в Edge/Selenium. Решается опять вручную - зайти на сайт, выйти, запустить скрипт.

Comment: Нет, не удалось